# Camel Route read Mail by call url IMAP Server, but will throw RuntimeCamelException if Content-Transfer-Encoding:quoted-printable

Tags: java, apache-camel, imap, quoted-printable, apache-camel-mail

everyone.
I have an application using camel route to call url IMAP to read mail and retrieve content, `from("{{route1.imap.protocol}}://{{route1.imap.host}}?username={{route1.imap.username}}&password={{route1.imap.password}}&consumer.delay={{route1.consumer.delay}}&fetchSize={{route1.fetchSize}}{{route1.otherOptions}}")"`
, most of the emails are read successfully by the application. But recently, we have encountered the client sends email with **Content-Transfer-Encoding:quoted-printable**, then the application will throw RuntimeCamelException

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Failed to extract body due to: Unknown encoding: quoted-printable . Exchange: Exchange[]. Message: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage@7970ebf3
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailBinding.extractBodyFromMail(MailBinding.java:278) ~[camel-mail-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailMessage.createBody(MailMessage.java:105) ~[camel-mail-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:47) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.createExchanges(MailConsumer.java:354) ~[camel-mail-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.poll(MailConsumer.java:128) ~[camel-mail-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102) [camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_281]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unknown encoding: quoted-printable 
    at javax.mail.internet.MimePartDataSource.getInputStream(MimePartDataSource.java:115) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.getContent(text_plain.java:80) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler.getContent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1454) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailBinding.extractBodyFromMail(MailBinding.java:250) ~[camel-mail-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown encoding: quoted-printable 
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.decode(MimeUtility.java:389) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at javax.mail.internet.MimePartDataSource.getInputStream(MimePartDataSource.java:108) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
```

I try to find the solution, which i have found maybe to set System property `mail.mime.ignoreunknownencoding` to "true", but i couldn't understand where to set `mail.mime.ignoreunknownencoding`. If anyone knows where to set? In Outlook, IMAP Server or my application properties?

And The application using dependency `camel-mail:2.18.1`, the dependency class `MailBinding.class` in the method `extractBodyFromMail` throw this exception. Or should I rewrite the `MailBinding` Class to override method `extractBodyFromMail`.

if anyone could help me, thank you very much.

Add some details the infos email

```
Date: Mon, 23 May 2022 12:50:19 +0000
From: <xxx@xxxx>
To: <xxx@xxxxx>, <xx@xxx>, <xx@xxx>
Subject: 1964790 - SCR_CNX_ADEP_STANDARD
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Message-ID: <991336a1-5f3d-449a-91af-c9a54cfb2e0f@xx.xx.local>
Return-Path: xx@xxx
X-Originating-IP: [10.1.128.112]
X-ClientProxiedBy: polar.airdolomiti.local (10.1.128.215) To
 polar.airdolomiti.local (10.1.128.215)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=xxxxxx.it; h=date:from:to:subject:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version:content-type:message-id; s=default; bh=2KBKjicvV/qIKyzYQAsZqkpDEKd3+uRQ8VlcakqOVx0=; b=E9wS98Kd+RrFNdRSOdPNwWT4Ga7P0/64LrM8plbjw1Fx7vtI1330ebvhVBjMNOuWlj8ctv+UmUs+GBnrEP/VNdLRv4vX+uPhq7JwWs9A6mlS0hWcOL4S711WLHrHdW8C4wXyQN4VmYfDRHx7jnhPwJBcY5RdWgjHf9sgOAfcdI4=
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 23 May 2022 12:50:20.4282
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
 e760ac37-bb92-4d82-685f-08da3cbacba1
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: d3fc41ce-14c2-4518-9065-8fe78ff84136:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
 PR2FRA01FT010.eop-fra01.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: e760ac37-bb92-4d82-685f-08da3cbacba1
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: PR0P264MB2439:EE_
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:
 CIP:151.11.112.123;CTRY:IT;LANG:en;SCL:-1;SRV:;IPV:NLI;SFV:SFE;H:mail.airdolomiti.it;PTR:mail.airdolomiti.it;CAT:NONE;SFS:;DIR:INB;
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 23 May 2022 12:50:20.2876
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: e760ac37-bb92-4d82-685f-08da3cbacba1
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: d3fc41ce-14c2-4518-9065-8fe78ff84136
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource:
 PR2FRA01FT010.eop-fra01.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: PR0P264MB2439
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.9451105
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.5273.022
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
```

Comment: Can you show the source message?  Quoted-Printable should absolutely be a support Content-Transfer-Encoding, but perhaps the sender set it in the wrong field (eg, Content-TYpe)

Comment: @Max i have added some message details. But normaly if Content-Type probleme,  why it throw Exception : ' Failed to extract body due to: Unknown encoding: quoted-printable' ? I couldn't understand. thanks for your reply.

Comment: That looks absolutely fine. Seems like something is wrong with your javax-mail.jar, since supporting quoted-printable is a basic functionality of a MIME/mail library.  For example, this javadoc specifically says that quoted-printable is supported: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html

Comment: As to your other question: the property is referring to a java property. You would normally provide them this way: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html#package.description  (see example in doc), but I’m not sure how you would pass that through camel

Comment: @Max, hello, even i have updated my dependency camel-mail:2.19.5, still throw exception **org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Failed to extract body due to: Unknown encoding: quoted-printable . Exchange: Exchange[]. Message: **. Do you have more idea?

Answer (score 0):

finally. I found the solution to modifier the properties before application run.it works.

> System.getProperties().setProperty("mail.mime.ignoreunknownencoding","true");
> SpringApplication.run(xxx.class, args);